# jquery validate properties to check multiple fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I would like to know if its possible to do this kind of jquery validation, maybe separate method will be needed.

I'm checking three fields for phone number, for area, prefix and linenumber respectively.

So, if none of the fields are entered in then the validation should be bypassed.

What I have now, is checking for example for the min and maxlength of each value, but for example if user will enter the value only in the area textbox correctly and then leave the other two textboxes blank, the validation is bypassed since the conditions are "met", either min or max or blank.

What I want to achieve is if any of the fields have value, then all three fields should have value, if none of them have values then validation is off.

This is what I have so far:

```
    $(this).validate({
        rules: {

            QUEST7_area: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 3
            },
            QUEST7_prefix: {
                minlength: 3,
                maxlength: 3
            },
            QUEST7_linenum: {
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 4
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            //  invalid handler will place the error
            var errorRect = $('div.errorrect');
            var message;

            if ((element[0].id == "QUEST7_area") || (element[0].id == "QUEST7_prefix") || (element[0].id == "QUEST7_linenum")) {
                        var afterElement = $('#QUEST7_linenum');
                        error.insertAfter(afterElement);
                        phoneErrorDisplayed = true;
            } 

            if (isNullOrWhiteSpace(errorRect.text())) {
                errorRect.text(message);
            }
        },
        messages: {

            QUEST7_area: $('#QUEST7').data('errormsg'),
            QUEST7_prefix: $('#QUEST7').data('errormsg'),
            QUEST7_linenum: $('#QUEST7').data('errormsg'),
        }

    });
```

Any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: The `.validate()` method is part of the jQuery Validate plugin, not the jQuery Validation Engine.  Please be more mindful when tagging.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, if none of the fields are entered in then the validation should be bypassed. ... What I want to achieve is if any of the fields have value, then all three fields should have value, if none of them have values then validation is off.

Within [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js), there is a rule/method called `skip_or_fill_minimum` which does exactly what you seem to be describing.

The rule will allow you to designate a minimum number of fields to be `required` from a designated group of fields... and if none are filled out, then all are skipped.

This method takes two parameters...

*1. min number of fields that must be filled out from the group.*

In your case, it's `3` since we want all three completed if any are filled in.

*2. selector that defines the group*

In your case, `input[name^='QUEST7']` will automatically select all `input` elements where the `name` *starts with* `"QUEST7"`.  Of course, you can assign a special class or devise any suitable selector that grabs only these three fields.

```
$(this).validate({
    rules: {
        QUEST7_area: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 3,
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,"input[name^='QUEST7']"]
        },
        QUEST7_prefix: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 3,
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,"input[name^='QUEST7']"]
        },
        QUEST7_linenum: {
            minlength: 4,
            maxlength: 4,
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,"input[name^='QUEST7']"]
        }
    },
    ....
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/ktn6d7dd/**

Optionally, you would use the [`groups`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) and [`errorPlacement`](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) options to consolidate and place a single error message.

Comment: your jsfiddle is correct way how this should work, I'm getting error locally, it says "TypeError: validator.elementValue is not a function". Any idea why this is popping up? Thx

Comment: @Laziale, can't see what you did wrong, so no idea.  Did you include the `additional-methods.js` file?  Did you carefully compare my jsFiddle to your page code?  It's probably a syntax error within your object literal.

Comment: @Laziale, looking back at your OP, I'm pretty sure you cannot define the custom messages using jQuery like that.  You'll need to enclose within a function. Again, compare my jsFiddle line by line, where you can see I have not defined custom messages like that.

Comment: the js file is included after all the jquery files, is that the correct placement? I'm able to step in to the file and you can see this screenshot where the error is happening http://i.gyazo.com/b01b9b1ae615df2e07a49e8a1ceba3ad.png

Comment: @Laziale, that is not helpful to me... you'll have to actually demonstrate the problem.  Break the jsFiddle to show the problem and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Do you have a minute for quick join.me session @Sparky Thx greatly appreciated

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72597/discussion-between-sparky-and-laziale).